# Anguar5 HttpClient POST error parsing plaintext response

Tags: post, angular5, plaintext

I try to access a REST API returning a plaintext response. However, when sending the request via Angular5 `HttpClient` I get following error:

> Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:8080/

Here is the code for my request:

```
  login(): void {
    let resultPromise: Promise<string> = login();

    resultPromise.then(token => this.onLogin(token), err => this.onLoginError(err));
  }

  login(loginData: LoginDataService): Promise<string> {
    let registerDTO = loginData.toRegisterDTO();
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        responseType: 'text/plain'
      })
    };
    return this.http.post<string>(this.userURL, registerDTO, httpOptions).toPromise();
  }

  private onLogin(token: string): void {
    this.loginData.setToken(token);
    this.router.navigate(["home"]);
  }

  private onLoginError(err: HttpErrorResponse) {
    this.loginData.logout();
    this.errorMsg = err.message;
  }
```

However, always `onLoginError` is called, passing following object:

```
{
  "headers": {
    "normalizedNames": {},
    "lazyUpdate": null
  },
  "status": 200,
  "statusText": "OK",
  "url": "http://localhost:8080",
  "ok": false,
  "name": "HttpErrorResponse",
  "message": "Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:8080",
  "error": {
    "error": {},
    "text": "fd39196f-08e3-4c54-82dd-99756f544fe2"
  }
}
```

I recognized that the `HttpResponse` does not contain the ContentType header, even though Chrome shows that the response contains the header.

Comment: Does anyone have an Idea why this is not working? I'm currently solving the problem by handling the error where i have access to the plaintext response body. IMO this is not very convenient